# Passing a parameter into a function bound through a template in Angularjs (disambiguation)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning from this site:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope

The example code does this:

js code:

```
// Some directive named kid defined here
.
.
.
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="chore">' +
      ' {{chore}}' +
      ' <div class="button" ng-click="done({chore:chore})">I\'m done!</div>'
.
.
.
```

html code:

```
<div ng-app="choreApp">
  <div ng-controller="ChoreCtrl">
    <kid done="logChore(chore)"></kid>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is this `({key: value})` syntax? If I change either the key or the value the whole thing stops workinng. How do you use this correctly? What are the rules?

Comment: Key is what you expect as an argument when you use your directive's function binding, i.e `done="logChore(chore)"` and value is the ngModel that you have bound to. Ex:- `done="logChore(arg1, arg2)"` then you would pass in as `ng-click="done({arg1:somethig, arg2:somethingelse})"`

Comment: @PSL What I don't understand is why I can't just pass the value like you normally would? Why do I need to know the key?

Comment: @PSL It seems the `({key : value})` is used to replace the passed in `key` from the view with a value that is sometimes stored inside the directive. This is odd... How is the programmer writing the view supposed to know the *magic* keys to use?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

In the html:

```
<your-directive your-attribute="yourMethod(yourArg)">
<your-directive your-attribute="yourMethod(yourOtherArg)">
```

In the js:

```
scope: {yourAttribute: '&'}
template: '<div ng-click"yourAttribue({yourArg : whateverValueYouWantItToRepresent,
                                       yourOtherArg : someValueYouAlsoWantToRepresent})">
```

Basically, it lets your replace predetermined 'keys' with any expression you desire. Not sure yet when that would be useful though. This does let you penetrate into the `isolate scope`.

Answer (score -1):

the key:value notation is required for method arguments when passing a method to your directive. For example you might want to provide for a callback method to be executed when your directive element is clicked:

in controller:

```
$scope.aMethod = function(arg1) {
  ...
};
```

in HTML:

```
<div my-directive some-method="aMethod()">
```

directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  scope: {
    aomeMethod: '&'
  }
  link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.bind('click', function (){
      scope.someMethod({arg1: 123});
    });
  }
});
```

The method defined in the controller takes an argument. However when you pass the method to the directive via the html notice the empty parenthesis. The directive has no idea about these args or what they should be called hence the need to explicitly pass the arg key along with the value.

Comment: If you look at the example in the link, it does something like `<div a-directive a-method="methodName(argName)">` and the key appears to be `argName` that is passed in the view.

Comment: where is the logChore function defined. It should take an arg with a key of chore. This is what the key within the directive refers to rather then the 'chore' within the directive

Comment: You might be wrong if I understand you correctly. It has nothing to do with the args `logChore` is taking. It has to do with the keys that are handed in the view and replacing them meaningfully.

See this for an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/B8G8UguA4jGdufwUA6zb?p=preview

The function takes `someOtherName` and the key is something else completely.